# Inline equation in latex with text

Tags: math-mode

Hi I want to write an inline equation with some texts like

```
Amplitude = 0.3 * Max_Amp_Of_Signal
```

How can I do it with LaTeX?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Enclose your formula in single `$`, as follows:

Text text text `$ \some \math \commands $` more text text text.

Note that if you use double `$$` instead, the formula will appear in it's own line, and the text will continue below.

Comment: Cant I include text inside math like $ \math some text $

Comment: Oh, yes, you can just put text in the equation. Use `\text{YOUR TEXT HERE}` so that it looks properly and spaces are reproduced. You might have to include `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble in order to use this command.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know it is deprecated. I always use the `align` environment from the amsmath package btw.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between $ and $$,. I did not know about that

Comment: Do I need space after `$`?

Answer (score 9):

It depends also on how you want your "variables" to appear; if you want them in the normal text font, then

```
$\textrm{Amplitude} = 0.3 \cdot \textrm{Max\_Amp\_Of\_Signal}$
```

is sufficient. Notice the `\_` to get the underscore, because `_` has a special meaning in LaTeX.